# How can I keep a conditional Object available within a function?

Tags: r, function, simulation

I am trying to make a simulation script to generate data from a Stan model for different numbers of subjects. I first use the model to simulate responses, then I use those simulated responses to re-fit the model.

My current approach is to generate the simulated responses on the first run of the function (when seed == 1) and assign the result to the global environment.

Is there a way to skip assigning the output of to the global environment but have that result be accessible for the second and later runs?

```
sim_data_fit <- function(nSim, nSubj) {
  set.seed(nSim)
  
  X <- as.matrix(data.frame(
    Var1 = sample(c(0,1), nSubj, replace = TRUE), 
    Var2 = sample(c(0,1), nSubj, replace = TRUE),
    Var3 = scale(rnorm(nSubj, mean = 50, sd = 2), center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)))
  
  if (nSim == 1) {
    sim_out <<- sampling(Sim_Mod, 
                         data = list(n = nSubj, 
                                     k = ncol(X), 
                                     X = X, 
                                     Y = rnorm(nSubj, mean = 65, sd = 10), 
                                     run_estimation = 0))        
  }  
  
  sim_data <- sim_out %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    select(contains("y_sim")) %>%
    .[, sample(ncol(.), nSubj)] %>%
    apply(., 2, sample, size = 1) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    rename("y_sim" = value)
  
  sampling(Sim_Mod, 
           data = list(n = nSubj, 
                       k = ncol(X), 
                       X = X, 
                       Y = sim_data$y_sim, 
                       run_estimation = 1)) 
  
}
```

`sim_out` is what I'm assigning only on the first run (I think). If I don't, I get an error that `sim_out` doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you initialize a list before the loop starts and then stick `sim.out` inside of the list? Or would this also not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I tried `sim_out <- list()`, but that throws an error because `sim_mod` is a `stanfit` object